# How can I create a list user inputs while using a loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

I'm creating a function that asks users how many days of sleep they want to report, then according to the answer it should ask for the day of the week and the hours slept. The function must return a list of lists with the days of the week and the amount of hours the user reported sleeping. Here's a picture attached of the desire output that I want from python.

[image]

So far I created a basic code that asks the user what the question asks but I seem to have trouble fitting in a while loop to keep asking the user the questions based on how many questions they want to report. Below is the code I have created so far.

```
def healthy():
    days=int(input("How many days do you want to report?:"))
    day=input("Day of the week:")
    hours=int(input("Hours Slept:"))
    print([day,hours])
healthy()
```

Comment: In the sample output, why are Monday and Tuesday in quotes, but not Wednesday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over `range(days)` and then store the result in a list of lists and return it from the function.

```
def healthy():
    days = int(input("How many days do you want to report?:"))
    output = []
    for i in range(days):
        day = input("Day of the week:")
        hours = int(input("Hours Slept:"))
        output.append([day, hours])
    return output
```

Output

```
result = healthy()
How many days do you want to report?:2
Day of the week:Mon
Hours Slept:8
Day of the week:Tue
Hours Slept:4

print(result)
#[['Mon', 8], ['Tue', 4]]
```

Comment: So I tried executing this code but it seems that  after I give off the last hour nothing is returned in idle as it seems the code ends abruptly

Comment: @anthonyceaser2021 try `result = healthy()` and then you can `print(result)` after it has run. I have updated the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach. Also you don't need a while loop, you can use `range(loops:int)`.

```
def healthy():
    info = []
    for i in range(int(input("How many days do you want to report?:"))):
        info.append([input("Day of the week:"),int(input("Hours Slept:"))])
    return info
print(healthy())
```

Comment: This seems a bit convoluted for a new Python user to understand. May be better to split it into separate lines to make the information easier to digest. Just a personal opinion :)